# Can I use template member functions as an alternative to the CRTP in order to implement static polymorphism?

Tags: c++, crtp, static-polymorphism

I want to implement the [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern using static polymorphism in C++.

Right now I have two classes `A` and `B` which are very similar. They have an identical public API and the exact same list of private data members. Most of the public member functions are also implemented identically but for some of them the two classes differ slightly in their implementation.

The situation looks somewhat like this:

```
class A {
public:
  /* Ctor etc... */
  int One() const;
  int Two() const;
  int Three() const; /* Calls PrivateA() internally */
private:
  int PrivateA() const;
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

class B {
public:
  /* Ctor etc... */
  int One() const; /* Identical to A::One() */
  int Two() const; /* Identical to A::Two() */
  int Three() const; /* Same as in A::Three() but calls PrivateB() instead of PrivateA() internally */
private:
  int PrivateB() const; /* Specific for B */
  /* Identical data members (type and semantics) to A */
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

I now want to reduce code duplication by moving all the shared code and data members to a base class and delegate to sub-class specific member functions from within the base class'. That is, something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
  int One() const;
  int Two() const;
  int Three() const; /* Should delegate to Private() internally */
private:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

class A : public Base {
private:
  int Private() const;
};

class B : public Base {
private:
  int Private() const;
};
```

I know I can solve this using the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in a manner similar to this:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
  int One() const;
  int Two() const;
  int Three() const; /* Should delegate to Private() internally */
private:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

class A : public Base<A> {
private:
  friend class Base<A>;
  int Private() const;
  int p;
};

class B : public Base<B> {
private:
  friend class Base<B>
  int Private() const;
  int q;
};

template<typename T>
int Base<T>::Three() const {
  return static_cast<const T*>(this)->Private();
}

int A::Private() const { return this->p; }
int B::Private() const { return this->q; }

int main() {
  A a{};
  B b{};

  /* Uses shared code from base class */
  a.One();
  b.One();

  /* Base class code statically dispatches to sub-class code via CRTP */
  a.Three(); /* Returns value of p */
  b.Three(); /* Returns value of q */

  return 0;
}
```

Now onto my question.

Is it possible to achieve the same result **without** making `Base` a template class? Can I accomplish the same thing using e.g. template member functions?

```
/* Note: no template */
class Base {
public:
  int One() const;
  int Two() const;

  template<typename T>
  int Three() const; /* Should delegate to Private() internally */
private:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

Comment: Not with a reasonable interface. The caller must provide T, and that is a public function, so other code needs to know how to call this, which is errorprone and tedious.  I'd just factor common code up, and implement differing code in the derived classes.

Comment: So there is no way to 'bind' `T` to e.g. `A` so that users can call `a.Three()` and the compiler figures out that `T` must be equal to `A`, without using a class template and inheritance?

Comment: That is, base class is reasonable assuming the similarities between two classes are not accidental.   Common code can be a problem by coupling classes that really arent related.  If one class needs to change and that affects other classes by making it configurable, it can introduce bugs.  Sometimes a little duplication is best, so code can change in isolation w/o getting complicated with several classes each needing to do their own thing tomorrow, but keeping it all tangled in one function.

Comment: To bind it would require some kind of wrapper function.  Perhaps you could use std::function or a member function ptr, and have derived types pass up which function to call, but simpler is to just put Three in the derived classes.  That binds it to the proper type without fancy and complicated templates with dubious benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is strictly "can I" - the answer is than "yes, you can, quite trivially":

```
template<typename T>
int Three() const {
    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->Private();
}
```

However, I would not advise this, since one of the benefits of CRTP is that it is (almost) impossible to misuse the cast - `static_cast` will almost always be valid.

With a snippet shown above, one could easily make a mistake and provide wrong template argument, and make `static_cast` undefined behavior.

Conclusion - there is no benefit in using this approach, but one can find a drawaback.

Comment: The drawback in the CRTP case is the increased compilation time and code bloat that results from the fact that all 'shared' member functions are compiled once for each sub-class. That is what I wanted to avoid by moving away from the class template solution. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @JonatanE you should experiment (with appropriate optimization levels). Link-time optimizations can be quite efficient.